# Android Room Database - Query validation for success or failure

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room, dao

We are using Room database in android to store the data.

Now, In Dao class we all perform various queries like Insert, Select, Delete, Update etc.

I want to know that How can We know that these queries executed successfully?

i.e If I am doing as below :

```
appDatabase.userDao().insert(userData)
```

How Can I notified that the user data is inserted in particular table and operation is successful ?

And Yes Is there any tools or plugin available through which we can see the data of Room database? (I have googled about it, but it was a bit confused regarding Device Monitor)

Please guide.

Comment: `Is there any tools or plugin` asking this is off-topic, you should know that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is explained in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data).

We can return a value for insert, update and delete operations to determine if it was successful or not.

```kotlin
@Insert
fun insert(item: ItemEntity): Long // returns row that entity was inserted at or -1 on failure

@Update
fun update(item: ItemEntity): Int // returns the number of rows updated successfully

@Delete
fun delete(item: ItemEntity): Int // returns the number of rows deleted successfully
```

And then when you do the operation:

```kotlin
val result = cache.insert(item.toItemEntity())
println("result is $result")
```

Queries don't seem to have an obvious way to implement this functionality though.

Comment: *or -1 on failure* where is that mentioned ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you re using room database to persist your data , the insert() method room returns a long value and you can use that value to check if data is persisted

```
 // make insert method returns a long value
  long insert()
```

- Then you can do get check for your long value

```
  long value = appDatabase.userDao().insert(userData)
   if(value == -1) no data insert 
   if(value ==  0) data inserted
```

PS : If i'm wrong , someone corrects me , thank you

Comment: if your dao class , make it return long

Comment: Please explain. not getting.

Comment: the returned value on success isn't zero but the SQLite `rowId`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign Dao functions to return a Long variable as follows

```
@Dao
interface DoctorCallDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(dcrData: DCRData):Long
}
```

Then you can catch this when you insert data into the database

```
 val state:Long= database.doctorCallDao.insert(dcrData)
        if(state>0) {
            //Successfully inserted
        } else {
           //Error occured
        }
```